# Здравствуйте, у меня вопрос по пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

«Я обычно просыпался в районе восьми и на самоизоляции, а сейчас работа пошла. И вчера дежурство, вообще, было».

Нужно ли в данном предложении окружать «вообще» запятыми?

Comment: Объясните, из чего вы исходите, допуская, что запятые нужны.

Answer (score 3):

*Я обычно просыпался в районе восьми и на самоизоляции, а сейчас работа пошла. И вчера дежурство, **вообще**, было.*

Окружайте, разрешается. Это **вводное слово** со значением "вообще говоря", так как значение **наречия** "вообще" сюда вообще не подходит.

**Справочник по пунктуации**

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_87

ВООБЩЕ, вводное слово и междометие

1. Вводное слово. То же, что «вообще говоря».

*Изнутри сарай не запирался, и, **вообще**, все эти сараи напоминают картонные ящики.*

! Не смешивать с употреблением в роли члена предложения (в знач. «в целом, в общем; совсем, при всех условиях»).

*Человеку **вообще** незачем сидеть на краю обрыва.* А. и Б. Стругацкие, Улитка на склоне.